# wkhtmltopdf does not create PDF of website

Tags: php, pdf, exec

I have found a tutorial on the internet about how to create a Wkhtmltopdf form where you can input your website URL and it will automatic create a PDF.

First I had to download the exec file wkhtmltopdf-amd64 at: 
http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2

There are two codes:

The form (pasted in the index.php):

```
<form action="http://localhost:8888/dev.crm/wkhtmltopdf.php" method="POST">Website:&nbsp;
<input name="url" size="30" type="text" value="http://www.examplewebsite.com" />
<input type="submit" value="transform into a pdf" /> </form>
```

The wkhtmltopdf.php file (pasted in the wkhtmltopdf.php):

```
<?php

/****************************
 BEGIN CONFIG
****************************/

// path to the program wkhtmltopdf
$conf['wkhtmltopdf'] = "http://www.mydomain.com/var/wkhtmltopdf-amd64";

// arguments for the programma wkhtmltopdf
// for example: --margin-top 50 --margin-bottom 30
// look: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/w/list
$conf['wkhtmltopdf_arg'] = "";

/****************************
 END CONFIG
****************************/

// reads url
$pattern = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";
if (!preg_match($pattern, $_REQUEST['url'])) {
die("no valid URL");
}

// temporary file
$output = "http://www.mydomain.com/dev.crm/tmp/output.pdf";

// gets the html of the document
$html = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);

// gets the title of document
preg_match("/\<title\>(.+)\<\/title\>/is", $html, $matches);

// looks if there is a title
if (empty($matches[1])) {
$matches[1] = "output.pdf";
}

// create pdf from html
system($conf['wkhtmltopdf'] . " " . $conf['wkhtmltopdf_arg'] . " " . $_REQUEST['url'] . " " . $output);

// output pdf to the browser
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $matches[1] . ".pdf\"");
readfile($output);

// remove pdf
unlink($output);

exit(0);
?>
```

The form works perfect and also calls the wkhtmltopdf.php, but somehow my server does not use the wkhtmltopdf-amd64. When I press the transform into a PDF button, I see that my webpage is loading, but it tries to open a PDF file, but I immidiadly get an error: 'the file '....pdf' cannot be openend, because it is empty. It saves the PDF, but the PDF size is 0 bytes.

Anyone has any idea how I can fix this issue? I think he does not use the wkhtmltopdf-amd64 file on my webserver.

//update

I saw that in the form I pasted localhost url. I changed that + line:

output ="/tmp/output.pdf"; now I got an error in a new page: Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/.../domains/.../public_html/.../wkhtmltopdf.php on line 40

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/.../domains/.../public_html/.../wkhtmltopdf.php:40) in /home/.../domains/.../public_html/.../wkhtmltopdf.php on line 43

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/.../domains/.../public_html/.../wkhtmltopdf.php:40) in /home/.../domains/.../public_html/.../wkhtmltopdf.php on line 44

Warning: readfile(/tmp/output.pdf) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../domains/.../public_html/stage/wkhtmltopdf.php on line 45

(the ... are my domains.)

Answer (score 1):

Please modify

```
$output = "http://www.mydomain.com/dev.crm/tmp/output.pdf";
```

with something like:

```
$output = "/tmp/output.pdf";
```

I really don't think you may output to some URL so, the solution is to have the output on your server.

Comment: Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons - it seems you are not able to use the system call. You may change that in php.ini

Comment: how do you mean change that in php.ini? i don't have that file inside my html files. what do i have to put inside it? it still does not work.

Comment: php.ini is the main php configuration file and it has nothing to do with your php/html files. It requires administrator privileges to make changes. I suggest to contact system administrator in order to get access to system() calls.

Comment: @HansdeVries. Please update the status atleast about this